# .htaccess rewriteRule doesn't work (example.com/?lang=en&p=help)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a problem with my .htaccess.

my url looks like this:
example.com/?lang=en&p=help
the first part work:
www.example.com/?lang=en&p=help
but the second part not. 
it should look like www.example.com/en/help or
it should look like www.example.com/en/help.html (i tried both)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?lang=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Comment: just to be clear:    www.example.com/en/help.html  should be treated as www.example.com/?lang=en&p=help ?
what do you mean by first and second part?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?lang=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

That will make your URL go from `www.example.com/?lang=en&p=help` to `www.example.com/en/help`

Comment: Note:   The is the opposite of what is required/desired 99.9% of the time.   I'm wondering if OP doesn't understand what modRewrite does and is wanting to modify urls in his response body (html)??